# ¿Cómo almacenar resultado de firebase, método ON, en una variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase

¿Cómo almacenar resultado de firebase, utilizando el método ON de Firebase, en una variable?

En Firebase se tiene algo parecido a esto:

```
- Datos
    - usuarios
        - ID1
            - nombre: "Miguel"
            - correo: miguel@ejemplo.com
        - ID2
            - nombre: "Juan"
            - correo: juan@ejemplo.com
```

Aquí es donde tengo el problema en JS, con el método: "ON" se tiene algo como esto:

```
// iniciamos Firebase:

miConexion = firebase.database().ref(Datos/usuarios)

// hacemos conexion con los datos:

var = datos={}

miConexion.on('value', function(ss){ // SnapShot
      datos = ss.val()
      console.log(datos['ID1'].nombre) // Miguel
      console.log(datos['ID2'].correo) // juan@ejemplo.com
})

// aqui el problema: (porque no se ejecuta primero que miConexion)

console.log(datos['ID1'].nombre) // Uncaught TypeError: 
                                 // Cannot read property 'ID1' of undefined
```

Haciendo varias pruebas logré sacar la variable con una PROMESA pero aplicando el METODO "ONCE" de Firebase, pero realmente necesito es con el METODO "ON" pero no logro hacerlo, aquí les dejo el JS con el **METODO "ONCE"**:

```
// iniciamos Firebase:

miConexion = firebase.database().ref(Datos/usuarios)

// hacemos conexion con los datos:

var = misDatos

// Declaramos la promesa:

misDatos = Promise.resolve(
              miConexion.once('value').then(function(ss){ // SnapShot
                 return ss.val()
              })
           )

// ahora ya tenemos la promesa almacenada en "misDatos" 
// y hacemos uso de ella cuando quiera y no exclusivamente 
// dentro de su instancia

misDatos.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result['ID1'].nombre) // Miguel
})

misDatos.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result['ID2'].correo) // juan@ejemplo.com
})
```

Deseo hacer esto pero con ON o si existe otra manera de poder acceder a los datos a través de una variable, estoy buscando una solución con JavaScript puro, no con jQuery.

Comment: Como ves el método `on` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) no devuelve una promesa. Supongo que esto es así porque este método puede ser llamado varias veces (cada vez que un nuevo valor se añade) y una promesa solo se puede resolver una vez. Me temo que deberás realizar la lógica que deseas dentro del callback. Si tuvieras una promesa como en el caso del método `once` y puedes utilizar el patrón async/await si que podrías obtener algo así `let value = await miConexion.once('value').then(s => s.val() )`

Comment: Hola @jose-hermosilla-rodrigo gracias por responder, en efecto mi problema esta con el método ON solo busco alguna sugerencia de alguien que se le haya ocurrido hacer algo así como en el ejemplo que puse de la promesa en el método ONCE pero aplicado al método ON. De todas formas probare el patrón async/await  en ON a ver que me sale. saludos.

Comment: Para ello tendrías que envolverlo en una función que devuelva una promesa `const on = ()=> new Promise ( (res, rej) =>{ miConexion.on(... resolver promesa )}` lo cual no está aconsejado hacer. Puedes utilizar bluebird para promisificar la función.  Pero tendría el mismo efecto que la función `once`

Comment: Como sugerencia busca una librería que utilice observables. Tendrás un código parecido a si utilizarlas promesas pero con la funcionalidad que deseas y la ventana ventaja de utilizar observables, por ejemplo : https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-firebase

Comment: Hola @jose-hermosilla-rodrigo gracias por responder, voy a seguir investigando y también voy a seguir tu concejo de buscar una librería e ir probando cual se adapta mejor a mis necesidades. saludos.

Comment: Yo tuve ese mismo problema. Y como dijo uno de ellos en el comentario utilice un observable que actualiza el valor de la variable y tambien en la vista. Yo utilizo Vuejs junto con firebase.

Answer (score 0):

espero que te ayude, a mi me funciono de esta manera, logre guardar el JSON con hijos en mi variable datos:

```
//Inicializo con mi configuración previa en la variable config firebase.
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//creó la referencia de mi base de datos en la variable dbRefObject
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('porfolio');

//Uso la función on, con la referencia. Uso snap para leer el valor
dbRefObject.on('value', snap => {
     const datos = JSON.stringify(snap.val(),null,3);

     //Muestro en consola el objeto JSON
     console.log(datos);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier función con estructura "callback" puede transformarse en promesa a.k.a. "promisificarse". En este caso declaro una función `onData` que espera como parámetro la conexión activa a Firebase. En ella devuelvo una promesa que se resolverá con lo que sea que obtenga de `ss.val()`.

El loop principal de tu app también ocurre dentro de una función asíncrona `initApp`, en donde luego de instanciar la conexón obtienes el valor de los datos haciendo `await` de lo que entregue la promesa resuelta en `onData`

```
async function onData(conn) {
    return new Promise(resolve=> {
       conn.on('value', (ss) => resolve(ss.val())
    })
}

async function initApp() {
   const miConexion = firebase.database().ref(Datos/usuarios)

   var datos = await onData(miConexion)
   console.log(datos['ID1'].nombre)
}
```

Si no quieres que tu loop principal exista dentro de una función, también puedes invocar el contenido de`initApp` en el espacio global

```
   const miConexion = firebase.database().ref(Datos/usuarios)

   onData(miConexion).then(datos => console.log(datos))
```

Si alguien pregunta por qué estoy pasando la conexión como parámetro en vez de dejar que todos ocupen la declaración global, es meramente para evitar side effects. Si el listener declarado en `.on('value', ...)`  se ejecuta una y otra vez entonces no hay control sobre el contenido de `datos`