# Recuperar variables de firebase database realtime, funciones

Tags: javascript, firebase

Buen día , una consulta a realtime database de firebase la hago asi.

```
  var horamess="";
  var ultmess ="";

firebase.database().ref('chat/key/mensajes')
.orderByChild('hora')
.limitToLast(1)
.on('value', function(lk){

    var lopij ="";
    var lopihhj ="";

  lk.forEach(element => lopij = element.val().mensaje);
  lk.forEach(element => lopihhj = element.val().hora);

   ultmess = lopij;
   horamess =lopihhj;


})

 console.log("//mensaje:*"+ultmess+"//hora:"+horamess);
```

Sin embargo cuando trato de obtener el valor de esas variables mediante el ***console.log()***... resulta que están vacios.

Comment: ¿Puedes intentar colocar el `console.log` justo después de la asignación de `ultmess` y `horamess`?

Comment: Alguien debería crear un wiki de comunidad sobre la asincronía en firebase. Las preguntas de este tipo, también en otros lenguajes, son de las más comunes en este sitio. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/276035/198326) hay una buena respuesta. No es exactamente la misma pregunta pero te servirá para entender el problema

Comment: buscando mejor, tu pregunta podría considerarse un duplicado de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75631/c%c3%b3mo-almacenar-resultado-de-firebase-m%c3%a9todo-on-en-una-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que es un problema de nivel de acceso, utiliza la función flecha para que su alcance no sea local.

fuente: [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
  var horamess="";
  var ultmess ="";

firebase.database().ref('chat/key/mensajes')
.orderByChild('hora')
.limitToLast(1)
.on('value',(lk) => {// utiliza funcion flecha aca

    //var lopij ="";   // puedes guardarlo directamente en las variables globales
    //var lopihhj =""; //

  lk.forEach(element => ultmess = element.val().mensaje);
  lk.forEach(element => horamess = element.val().hora);



})

 console.log("//mensaje:*"+ultmess+"//hora:"+horamess);
```